# adding elements to list not working in c# and .net

Tags: c#, list, element, addition

I have a list:

```cs
private static List<Contact> List()
{
    var contacts = new List<Contact>() { new Contact("Bob",123) };
    return contacts;
}
```

and a method, which adds new contact to the list:

```cs
private static void AddContact()
{
    var contact = new Contact("Max", 123);
    List().Add(contact);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AddContact();
    ShowAllContacts();
}

private static void ShowAllContacts()
{ 
    foreach(var contact in List())
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(contact.GetContactName() + ", "
          + contact.GetContactNumber());
    }
}
```

But when I try to display the whole list, it only displays the elements that are in the list when it was instantiated (`Bob,123`) and doesn't displays `Max,123`.

Comment: Please provide the code for the ShowAllContacts() method

Comment: You need to define a global variable to save the value of List().

Comment: Unless you store the return value of `List()` you are just creating a new `List` and then throwing it away immediately.

Answer (score 0):

When `AddContact()` ist called a new List is created as `List()` is called. Then you add the contact to this new list and do not return the list or store it in any variable. Therefore the created list with the "Max" contact in it is "lost" as it is not reachable anymore and will be removed by the garbage collector.

Then in `ShowAllContacts()` you are calling `List()` again which creates a NEW list which does not have the "Max" contact in it as it has not been added to this list but to the one that was created in `Main()`.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a list

What you have there is a method, not a list. That method returns a list. If you call it once, you get a list, if you call it again, you get another list.

> but when i try to display the whole list

There is no **the** whole list. You call the method twice, so you have 2 lists.

If you want to have 1 list only, you need to call the method only once and then remember the result in a variable.

Your code should look like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var contacts = List();
    AddContact(contacts);
    ShowAllContacts(contacts);
}

private static List<Contact> List()
{
    var contacts = new List<Contact>() { new Contact("Bob",123)};
    return contacts;
}

private static void AddContact(List<Contact> whichListToAddTo)
{
    var contact = new Contact("Max", 123);
    whichListToAddTo.Add(contact);
}

private static void ShowAllContacts(List<Contact> whichListToShow) 
{ 
     foreach(var contact in whichListToShow) 
     { 
           Console.WriteLine(contact.GetContactName() + ", " + contact.GetContactNumber()); 
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a static List variable, then created a method to initialize the List. I have also amended the AddContact method.

```
static List<Contact> contacts;
       
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        initializeList();
        AddContact();
        ShowAllContacts();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void initializeList() //Initialize the list with the first item
    {
         contacts = new List<Contact>() { new Contact("Bob", 123) };
    }

    private static List<Contact> List()
    {
        return contacts;
    }

    private static void AddContact() // Add new items to the existing contacts list
    {
        var contact = new Contact("Max", 123);
        contacts.Add(contact);
    }

    private static void ShowAllContacts()
    {
        foreach (var contact in List())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(contact.GetContactName() + ", "
              + contact.GetContactNumber());
        }
    }
```